# Java - Merge sort array

Tags: java, mergesort

I'm making an algorithm for a shop. I have made an array which contains customer information. Now I want to implement a merge-sort on this array and sort it on age. This is my code for the customer class:

```
public class Customer{

private int customerID;
private String name;
private int age;
private char gender;
private String email;

public List<Customer> customerList = new ArrayList<Customer>();

public Customer(String name, int age, char gender, String email) {
    this.customerID = customerList.size();
    this.name= name;
    this.age= age;
    this.gender= gender;
    this.email = email;
    customerList.add(this);
}
public int getCustomerID() {
    return customerID;
}

public void setCustomerID(int customerID) {
    this.customerID = customerID;
}

public String getName() {
    return name;
}

public void setName(String name) {
    this.name= name;
}

public int getAge() {
    return age;
}

public void setAge(int age) {
    this.age = age;
}

public char getGender() {
    return gender;
}

public void setGender(char gender) {
    this.gender = gender;
}

public String getEmail() {
    return email;
}

public void setEmail(String email) {
    this.email = email;
}
```

}

This is my merge-sort:

```
    private int[] helper;
private int number;

public void sort(Klant[] values) {
    this.customerList= values;                      <---Error
    number = values.length;
    this.helper = new int[number];
    mergesort(0, number - 1);
}

private void mergesort(int low, int high) {
    // check if low is smaller then high, if not then the array is sorted
    if (low < high) {
        // Get the index of the element which is in the middle
        int middle = low + (high - low) / 2;
        // Sort the left side of the array
        mergesort(low, middle);
        // Sort the right side of the array
        mergesort(middle + 1, high);
        // Combine them both
        merge(low, middle, high);
    }
}

private void merge(int low, int middle, int high) {

    // Copy both parts into the helper array
    for (int i = low; i <= high; i++) {
        helper[i] = customerList[i];
    }

    int i = low;
    int j = middle + 1;
    int k = low;
// Copy the smallest values from either the left or the right side back
    // to the original array
    while (i <= middle && j <= high) {
        if (helper[i] <= helper[j]) {
            customerList[k] = helper[i];
            i++;
        } else {
            customerList[k] = helper[j];
            j++;
        }
        k++;
    }
    // Copy the rest of the left side of the array into the target array
    while (i <= middle) {
        customerList[k] = helper[i];
        k++;
        i++;
    }

}
```

On the line with:
this.customerList = values; I get an error: incompatible types Customer[] cannot be converted to List

My question is how can I fix this error and is my merge-sort correct this way?

Edit 1:
@Jens 
Your first option:
    this.customerList= Arrays.asList(values);

fixed the error. But now I'm getting an error on this line:

```
            helper[i] = customerList[i];
```

It says: array required, but List found

Does anybody know how to fix this?

Comment: `public List<Customer> customerList = new ArrayList<Customer>();` This is a list. You're passing a `Klant[]` array. Arrays and ArrayLists are different. You were probably looking for `Customer[] customerList;`

Comment: You can either cover your list to an array or use a list through out !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can`t assign a Array to a list.

Try

```
 this.customerList= Arrays.asList(values);
```

or Change the method parameetr to `List<Customer>`

```
public void sort(List<Customer> values) {
```

Answer (score 0):

Why not to use [Collections.sort()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#sort(java.util.List)) method? It also uses merge sort algorithm.

```
List<Klant> list = Arrays.asList(values);
Collections.sort(list);
```

Or you can use [Arrays.sort()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#sort(T[],%20java.util.Comparator)) as well, but it does not use merge sort.

But keep in mind that will you need it to implement [Comparable](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Comparable.html) interface for your `Klant` class.

UPDATE:

In case if you need to implement merge sort algorithm by yourself, probably you need to change `customerList` variable type from `List` to array of `Customer[]`. If you would like to use the list you can do as [Jens](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28117799/1889928) suggested, but use [add()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/List.html#add(E)) method of `List` and not assign the value via `=`.

Comment: Well I assume the task is to create a mergesort, so sorting it using a collections class is not really accomplishing the task with a mergesort.